"User cannot be authenticated with the token provided" when deploying a Cloud Function with a GitHub Package inside
I'm experiencing an issue with a NestJS project I am working on. The project includes a set of Firebase Functions, and I'm trying to integrate a private Node package published through GitHub Packages.
The package is named @letvarhq/oboe. In order to make it work, I have created a .npmrc file in the root folder of the project with the following content:
@letvarhq:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/letvarhq
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${GH_PACKAGES_ACCESS_TOKEN}

GH_PACKAGES_ACCESS_TOKEN is a personal access token created on my personal GitHub with the read:packages scope, and it is injected in the project through a .env file:
[...]
GH_PACKAGES_ACCESS_TOKEN="the access token"
[...]

Then, I installed the package correctly through npm i @letvarhq/oboe, and it works fine.
Now I want to deploy the Firebase Functions with GitHub Actions. The pipeline steps to build and deploy the Functions are the following:
[...]
       - name: Set up Node.js
         uses: actions/setup-node@v3
         with:
           registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com/'
       - name: Install npm packages
         run: |
           npm install
       - name: Deploy to Firebase
         uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
         with:
           args: deploy -P dev --only functions,hosting:api-dev
env:
  GCP_SA_KEY: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }} 
  GH_PACKAGES_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PACKAGES_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

However, when I try to deploy - either locally with firebase deploy -P dev --only functions,hosting:api-dev --debug or via GitHub Actions - I get the following error:
npm error code E401
nom error 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@letvarhq/oboe/0.1.7/5929fe5e45cf80a336a7d2aaf6a087c5ff1340d7 
- unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2024-08-30T14_39_40_220Z-debug-0.log;
Error ID: beaf8772

Any idea why I keep getting this error, and how can I get the logs at /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2024-08-30T14_39_40_220Z-debug-0.log?
